# How to import my data from SoSci Survey with the API to R?

Tags: r

I had some struggle with the information SoSci Survey provided, therefor I will share my knowledge in the answer.

My UI is in german. Sorry if the english names are not exactly the same.

Answer (score 0):

Go to collected data -> download data -> GNU R

Click on enable API import

Now copy the command to R and execute it

It should look like: eval(parse("https://survey.ise.tu-darmstadt.de/token_offering/index.php?act=SomeRandomCharsQuality&useSettings&rScript", encoding="UTF-8"))

Your default dataframe name is ds but can give it another name on the website.

Try e.g. summary(ds)